# installing vmware view server manager

Tags: vmware-view

I am installing vmware view on windows 2003 64bit. i get an error about port 80 being in use. How can sort this?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it by stopping whatever is running on port 80.

Are you running a webserver, IIS or Apache etc. on the machine?

Any other web-based apps?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use TCP View (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to see which application is currently listening on port 80.  Once you figure out what is currently listening on port 80 you will need to reconfigure that application to listen on an alternate port. Or at least stop it long enough so you can install the application and then change which port Vmware is using.